# Is there an algebraic proof for $\sum_{m=k}^{n-k} \binom{m}{k}\binom{n-m}{k} = \binom{n+1}{2k+1}, n\ge2k\ge0$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

$\sum_{m=k}^{n-k} \binom{m}{k}\binom{n-m}{k} = \binom{n+1}{2k+1}, n\ge2k\ge0$

An combinatorial proof of the identity above states as follow:

(1)Number of ways of picking (2k+1) numbers from 1 to (n+1) should be $\binom{n+1}{2k+1}$

(2)We pick (2k+1) numbers from 1 to (n+1) with median value (m+1).  Then, k numbers must be selected from 1~m, and the other k numbers must be chosen from (m+2)~(n+1). Thus there are $\binom{m}{k}\binom{n-m}{k}$ ways for picking (2k+1) numbers with median value (m+1). Since $n-k\ge m\ge k$, there are total $\sum_{m=k}^{n-k} \binom{m}{k}\binom{n-m}{k}$ ways.

Since (1)=(2), the statement is true.
But is it possible to sketch an algebraic proof that doesn't require building combinatorial models?

Comment: Consider coefficient of $x^{n}$ in $[x^k(1-x)^{k+1}][x^k(1-x)^{k+1}]$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an algebraic proof based upon generating functions. It is convenient  to use the *coefficient of* operator  $[z^n]$ to  denote the coefficient of  $z^n$  in  a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
[z^k](1+z)^n=\binom{n}{k}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{m=k}^{n-k}}&\color{blue}{\binom{m}{k}\binom{n-m}{k}}\\
> &=\sum_{m=0}^{n-2k}\binom{m+k}{m}\binom{n-m-k}{k}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{m=0}^{n-2k}\binom{-k-1}{m}(-1)^m\binom{n-m-k}{k}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{m=0}^\infty[z^m](1-z)^{-k-1}[u^k](1+u)^{n-m-k}\tag{3}\\
> &=[u^k](1+u)^{n-k}\sum_{m=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{1+u}\right)^{m}[z^m](1-z)^{-k-1}\tag{4}\\
> &=[u^k](1+u)^{n-k}\left(1-\frac{1}{1+u}\right)^{-k-1}\tag{5}\\
> &=[u^k](1+u)^{n-k}u^{-k-1}(1+u)^{k+1}\tag{6}\\
> &=[u^{2k+1}](1+u)^{n+1}\tag{7}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\binom{n+1}{2k+1}}\tag{8}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we shift the index to start with $m=0$ and use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.
- In (2) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (3) we apply the  *coefficient of* operator twice and we set the upper bound of the series to $\infty$ without changing anything since we are adding zeros only.
- In (4) we  use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and we apply the rule $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$.
- In (5) we apply the substitution rule of the *coefficient of* operator with $z=\frac{1}{1+u}$
  \begin{align*}
  A(u)=\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_m u^m=\sum_{m=0}^\infty u^m [z^m]A(z)
  \end{align*}
- In (6) we do some simplifications.
- In (7) we do some more simplifications and apply the same rule as we did in (4).
- In (8) we select the coefficient of $u^{2k+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

More generally:

> **Theorem 1.** For every nonnegative integers $x$, $y$ and $n$, we have
>   \begin{equation}
> \dbinom{n+1}{x+y+1}=\sum_{m=0}^{n}\dbinom{m}{x}\dbinom{n-m}{y}.
> \end{equation}

This equality rewrites as
\begin{equation}
\dbinom{n+1}{x+y+1} = \sum_{m=x}^{n-y} \dbinom{m}{x}\dbinom{n-m}{y} ,
\end{equation}
because all addends $\dbinom{m}{x}\dbinom{n-m}{y}$ are zero except for those where $x \leq m \leq n-y$.

Your identity is the particular case of the latter equality for $x = k$ and $y = k$.

Your nice bijective proof of the original identity can easily be generalized to a proof of Theorem 1; just count all ways of picking an $\left(x+y+1\right)$-element subset of $\left\{1,2,\ldots,n+1\right\}$ according to the value of the $\left(x+1\right)$-th-lowest element of the subset. Indeed, for any given $m \in \left\{0,1,\ldots,n\right\}$, picking an $\left(x+y+1\right)$-element subset $S$ of $\left\{1,2,\ldots,n+1\right\}$ whose $\left(x+1\right)$-th-lowest element is $m+1$ is tantamount to picking an $x$-element subset of $\left\{1,2,\ldots,m\right\}$ (which will contain the $x$ elements of $S$ lower than $m+1$) and picking a $y$-element subset of $\left\{m+2,m+3,\ldots,n+1\right\}$ (which will contain the $y$ elements of $S$ higher than $m+1$). This gives $\dbinom{m}{x}\dbinom{n-m}{y}$ for the number of choices.

As for other proofs:

- An elementary proof is given in Proposition 3.32 **(f)** in [Darij Grinberg, *Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of algebra*, Version of 10 January 2019](https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2019-01-10). The proposition is obtained from Vandermonde convolution by several applications of upper negation.
- Theorem 1 is also equivalent to the identity proven in [Proof of $\sum_{m=0}^{n}\binom{m}{j}\binom{n-m}{k-j}=\binom{n+1}{k+1}$ (Another form of the Chu–Vandermonde identity)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2409187/proof-of-sum-m-0n-binommj-binomn-mk-j-binomn1k1-another?rq=1) (just set $j = x$ and $k = x+y$); the proof uses generating functions.

Answer (score 0):

A direct calculation:

$$\sum_{m=k}^{n-k}\binom{m}{k}\binom{n-m}{k}=\sum_{m=k}^{n-k}\binom{m}{m-k}\binom{n-m}{n-m-k}$$$$=\sum_{m=k}^{n-k}\left(-1\right)^{m-k}\binom{-k-1}{m-k}\left(-1\right)^{n-m-k}\binom{-k-1}{n-m-k}$$$$=\left(-1\right)^{n}\sum_{m=k}^{n-k}\binom{-k-1}{m-k}\binom{-k-1}{n-m-k}=\left(-1\right)^{n}\binom{-2k-2}{n-2k}$$$$=\binom{n+1}{n-2k}=\binom{n+1}{2k+1}$$

Hence we showed that:
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{\sum_{m=k}^{n-k}\binom{m}{k}\binom{n-m}{k}=\binom{n+1}{2k+1}}$$

As desired.