# Finding value of $\sum^{10}_{k=2}\binom{k}{2}\binom{12-k}{2}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem, combinatorial-proofs

> Finding value of $$\sum^{10}_{k=2}\binom{k}{2}\binom{12-k}{2}$$

Solution I tried:

$$(1+x)^{10}=1+\binom{10}{1}x+\binom{10}{2}x^2+\cdots +\binom{10}{10}x^{10}$$

$$(x+1)^{10}=x^{10}+\binom{10}{1}x^9+\binom{10}{2}x^7+\cdots +\binom{10}{10}$$

I did not find how do multiply terms such that i get my result. Help me

Comment: Hint:  it's not so hard to do this by brute force.  If you want a more elegant method, first prove combinatorially that this sum represents the number of ways to choose $5$ elements from $13$ objects.

Comment: lulu can you plz explain me

Comment: Suppose you are choosing $5$ objects out of $13$.  list the choices as $n_1,\cdots, n_5$.  Let $n_3=k+1$.  Take it from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To complete the method sketched in the comments.

The answer is $\binom {13}5$.

To see this, suppose we are choosing $5$ values from $\{1,\cdots, 13\}$. Order the choices as $n_1<\cdots <n_5$.  Let $n_3=k+1$.  Clearly $2≤k≤10$.  Given a choice of such an $n_3$ we see that we are asked to choose $2$ values from $\{1,\cdots, k\}$ and $2$ from $\{k+2,\cdots, 13\}$.  There are $\binom k2$ ways to do the former and $\binom {13-(k+2)+1}2=\binom {12-k}2$ ways to do the latter.  Hence the number of choices with a given $n_3$ is the product $\binom {k}2\times \binom {12-k}2$.  Summing over $k$ we see that $$\binom {13}5=\sum_{k=2}^{10}\binom {k}2\times \binom {12-k}2$$ as desired.

Comment: Brilliant solution. You may want to mention that $n_3 = k+1$ can take values from $3$ to $13$ hence the sum runs on $k$ from $2$ to $12$.

Comment: @feynhat   $k+1$ can't be greater than $11$, since $13≥n_5>n_4>n_3=k+1$.  Thus $3≤k+1≤11$ or, $2≤k≤10$.

Comment: In a way, you're both right; the $k\in\left\{11,\,12\right\}$ terms vanish because $12-k<2$.

Comment: @lulu Yes. I meant to say "$n_3$ takes values from $3$ to $\textbf{11}$".

Answer (score 4):

It is [Chu–Vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)

$$\sum^{10}_{k=2}\binom{k}{2}\binom{12-k}{2}=\sum^{10}_{k=2}\binom{k}{2}\binom{12-k}{4-2}={12+1\choose 4+1}=1287.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$=\sum_{r=2}^{10}\dfrac{r(r-1)(12-r)(11-r)}4$$

Use the formulas in [Geometric interpretation for sum of fourth powers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241760/geometric-interpretation-for-sum-of-fourth-powers)

Answer (score 1):

$$S_{(10,2)} = \sum^{10}_{k=2}\binom{k}{2}\binom{12-k}{2}$$
You can generalize the question as:
\begin{align}
S_{(n,\,r)} &= \sum^{n}_{k=r}\binom{k}{r}\binom{(n+r)-k}{r}\\
\end{align}

Set $(n+r) = m\,$ and we get 
\begin{align}
S_{(n,\,r)} &= \sum^{n}_{k=r}\binom{k}{r}\binom{m-k}{r}= \binom{m+1}{2r+1}\\
\end{align}
(See [Another form of the Chu–Vandermonde identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2409187/proof-of-sum-m-0n-binommj-binomn-mk-j-binomn1k1-another?rq=1) and [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2587941/353218) )

So

> $$S_{(n,\,r)} = \binom{n+r+1}{2r+1}$$

In your case
$$S_{(10,2)} = \binom{10+2+1}{2\cdot 2+1} = \binom{13}{5} = 1287$$