# Closed form for $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^{r}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients, closed-form

One of the most important and basic identities in binomial summations in [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) which states :

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{r}\binom{m}{k}\binom{n}{r-k}=\binom{m+n}{r}$$

The identity [can be generalized](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2409187/proof-of-sum-m-0n-binommj-binomn-mk-j-binomn1k1-another/3576308#3576308) to the case when more than two binomial coefficients are multiplied.

Setting $m,r \mapsto n$ follows:

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{n-k}=\binom{2n}{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2$$

Which is very well-known.

One of the questions related to this summation is :

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^{4}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{\color{red}{n}}{\color{blue}{k}}\binom{\color{red}{n}}{\color{blue}{k}}\binom{\color{red}{n}}{\color{blue}{n-k}}\binom{\color{red}{n}}{\color{blue}{n-k}}$$

I thought that the answer would be $\binom{4n}{2n}$, but this is not right in general and I don't know why, since the sum of the red and blue parts is independent of the index (is a fixed number),so that's why I used the convolution (It would be highly appreciated if someone explain where was I wrong).

My question is :
Does there exist any closed formula for :

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^{r}$$

Where $r \in \mathbb N$.

One of the  identities related to this question is Dixon’s Identity which has been mentioned [here](https://math.wvu.edu/~hgould/Vol.4.PDF) (page 3).

[wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Sum%22%2C%20%22sumlowerlimit%22%7D%20-%3E%220%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Sum%22%2C%20%22sumfunction%22%7D%20-%3E%22C%28n%2Ck%29%5E4%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Sum%22%2C%20%22sumvariable%22%7D%20-%3E%22k%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Sum%22%2C%20%22sumupperlimit2%22%7D%20-%3E%22n%22) does not give a closed form.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your main question right now, but the reason your $\binom nk^4$ sum does not work is that the sum does not range over *all* terms $\binom na \binom nb \binom nc \binom nd$ where $a+b+c+d=2n$, only those where $a=b$ and $c=d$.

Comment: Try $r=3$ first. This should give a sufficient disappointment.

Comment: @ metamorphy, you are totally right

Comment: I didn't think it through and I get the problem now. So basically $ (^1_0)^4+(^1_1)^4 =2 \ne 4=C(4,2)$. And the reason for that is if we consider $ k_1+k_2+k_3+k_4=2$ where $k_i \in {0,1}$, we have $\frac{4!}{2!2!}$ solutions and thus six ways to get the coefficient of $x^2$ from $(1+x)^4$

Comment: @ metamorphy , you are right, and I guess you meant $\binom{4}{2}=6$